# Why do I sometimes have 10,000+ tombstones when I don't do DELETEs?

Tags: cassandra

When doing a repair on a Cassandra node, I sometimes see a lot of tombstone logs. The error looks like this:

```
org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.TombstoneOverwhelmingException: Scanned over 100001 tombstone rows during query 'SELECT * FROM my_keyspace.table_foo WHERE token(<my params>) >= token(<my params>) AND token(<my params>) <= 2988334221698479200 LIMIT 2147385647' (last scanned row partition key was ((<my params>), 7c650d21-797e-4476-93d5-b1248e187f22)); query aborted
```

I have read [here](https://thelastpickle.com/blog/2016/07/27/about-deletes-and-tombstones.html) that tombstones are inserted as a way to mark a record as deleted. However, I don't see any code in this project that runs a delete on this table - just a read and an insert. What am I missing - how can I prevent these TombStoneOverwhelmingExceptions?

Here is the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE my_keyspace.table_foo(
    foo1 text,
    year int,
    month int,
    foo2 text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((foo1, year, month), foo2)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (foo2 ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND default_time_to_live = 6912000
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, I don't see any code in this project that runs a delete on this table - just a read and an insert.

The code might not be running `DELETE`s, but the table definition tells Cassandra to delete anything >= 80 days old.  TTLs create tombstones.

```
AND default_time_to_live = 6912000
```

So the thought behind TTLs in a time series model, is that they are typically ordered by timestamp in descending order.  What ends up happening, is that most use cases tend to care only about recent data, and the descending order by timestamp causes the tombstones to end up on the "bottom" of the partition, where they are rarely (if ever) queried.

To create that effect, you'd need to create a new table with a definition something like this:

```
PRIMARY KEY ((foo1, year, month), created_time, foo2)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (created_time DESC, foo2 ASC)
```

Comment: That TTL was key. I lowered `gc_grace_seconds` to 2 days instead of 10 days, and I haven't seen any TombstoneOverwhelmingExceptions in 8 hours now! If it pops back up, I think I'll try lowering that `gc_grace_seconds` more so that the tombstones get picked up more often.

Answer (score 0):

@anthony, here is my pov.

- As a first step, don't let tombstones inserted into the table
- Use the full primary key during the read path so we skip having to read the tombstones. Data modeling is key to designing the tables based on your access patterns required on the reading side
- We could go and adjust `min_threshold` and set it to `2` to do some aggressive tombstone eviction
- Similarly, we could tweak [common options](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-4.0.1/doc/source/operating/compaction/index.rst#common-options) (for e.g. `unchecked_tombstone_compaction` set to `true` or other properties/options) to evict them faster
- I would encourage you to view a *similar* question and the answers that are documented [here](https://community.datastax.com/questions/2387/will-updating-records-create-tombstones.html)